# How would I access trac on mobile phone?

Tags: mobile, trac

as a programmer I live with Trac, how do you go about accessing trac projects via a mobile phone, nokia/android/iphone/windows mobile, the mobile platform is not important, I can get a new phone but trac is there to stay.

Answer (score 1):

You could always try to use the phone's browser app to surf to your Trac page.

If you have your Trac in your LAN and want to access it from Internet, you will need to configure your firewall to be able to do so.